# Difference between exact greedy/reluctant X{n}?

Tags: regex, regex-greedy, reluctant-quantifiers

In the documentation for the Java [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class, I see that the exact quantifier `X{n}` has both greedy and reluctant forms:

> **Greedy quantifiers**
>
> - X{n}    X, exactly n times
> - ...
>
> **Reluctant quantifiers**
>
> - X{n}?   X, exactly n times
> - ...

The documentation gives general examples of the difference between greedy and reluctant behavior, but doesn't give any examples for the exact quantifiers.

At first I thought, "Well, maybe the difference is that `X` itself could match in difference ways." But then `X` can have its own greedy/reluctant specifiers inside it, and sure enough I tested it and that's not a difference ([greedy](https://regex101.com/r/hQ5dX8/1) vs [reluctant](https://regex101.com/r/cY2cL4/1)).

Given that, in either case, it is going to match exactly `n` times, is there any difference between the behavior of the two?

Comment: `X{2}` = `X{2}?`. The first is shorter - that is all the difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reluctant vs greedy only makes sense when a variable length match is possible; a reluctant quantifier will match the minimum possible, and greedy the maximum.

To distinguish behaviour of a limited quantity, it must have a *range*, ie the quantity must have a different minimum and maximum. To illustrate:

Given the input `1234567`, the groups captured are:

```
(\d{2,3})(\d+)  -> (123)(4567)
(\d{2,3}?)(\d+) -> (12)(34567)
```

When there is just a fixed quantity, eg `\d{2}` there is no difference in behaviour by adding a `?`.

Comment: This sounds like a great answer but do you know of any documentation that would support it?

Comment: The question mark in all cases means *reluctant* match, which means "as few of the preceding quantity as possible but still match". In this case, the smallest quantity in the range  of `{2,3}` that can still create a match overall is `2`.